# How can I send out parameter to web method from jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, out-parameters

Im triying to send out parameter to webmethod. I cant change web method because its not mine. I need to use it with only jquery.

Web method example;

```
[WebMethod]
public static string getValue(int id, out string name)
{
   name = (id * 5).ToString();
   return "Success";
}
```

Jquery example;

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     getValue();
 });

 function getValue() {
     $.ajax({
         url: "../WebMethods.aspx/getValue",
         type: 'post',
         contentType: "application/json",
         dataType:"json",
         data: JSON.stringify({ id: 0, name: "" }),
         success: function (data) {
             console.log(data);
         }
     });
 }
```

I need name value in success function. Is it possible? I can call it in c# and its working. Bu I need it to work in ajax method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use in your success method.

```
$(this).attr('data')
```

for your case it should be like :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 getValue();
```

});

```
function getValue() {
     $.ajax({
         url: "../WebMethods.aspx/getValue",
         type: 'post',
         contentType: "application/json",
         dataType:"json",
         data: JSON.stringify({ id: 0, name: "" }),
         success: function (data) {
             console.log(data);


         console.log( $(this).attr('data') );  
         }
     });
 }
```

---update 2

try this

```
 var Data = { id: 0 , name : "" };

function getValue() {
     $.ajax({
         url: "../WebMethods.aspx/getValue",
         type: 'post',
         contentType: "application/json",
         dataType:"json",
         data: Data ,
         success: function (data) {
             console.log(data);


         console.log( Data.id );  
         }
     });
 }
```

Comment: I have added one more solution please try that..:)

Comment: Data didnt change. name is what I send

Comment: its not changed..I have defined it on the top..see var Data = { id: 0 , name : "" };

Comment: I saw that but I think you misunderstood. When I send {id:1, name:""}. I want name "5". Your Data is only local variable. I want to send this data to server, and change wtihout return. I think its not possible

Comment: ohh sorry..ya i misunderstood your question :) No that is not possible I guess..Thanks